# Mongoengine's Inconsistent behaviour returns result of aggregate() as Cursor object in ArchLinux and String in Ubuntu

Tags: python, pymongo, bottle, mongoengine

I have been using `mongoengine` for handling MongoDb along with BottlePy.

Recently I used one of its aggreagation APIs.

```
data.postsByYear = Post._get_collection().aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'isDraft' : False
        }
    },
    {
        '$sort': {
            'published': -1
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': {'year': {'$year':'$published'}},
            'posts': {'$push': { 'title': '$title', 'id': '$_id'}}
        },
    },
    {
        '$sort': {
            '_id': -1
        }
    }
])
```

In my ArchLinux machine with python 2.7 I had the output which was a Cursor object just like the what the docs have mentioned.

> In the mongo shell, if the cursor returned from the db.collection.aggregate() is not assigned to a variable using the var keyword, then the mongo shell automatically iterates the cursor up to 20 times. See Cursors for cursor behavior in the mongo shell and Iterate a Cursor in the mongo Shell for handling cursors in the mongo shell.

But in my Ubuntu EC2 server in Amazon the response of the function is a string. I am not sure if this is a pymongo bug or mongoengine bug so did not post this as an issue.

Just making sure if this is not a mistake of mine.

Plus is there a workaround for this ?